# have bothered or have been bothering

Tags: meaning

When I say "Sorry for bothering you" that means I'm still bothering you .

But if it has just finished at the time of speaking but  lasted for a long time shall I  say: **"Sorry to have bothered you."** or **"Sorry because I have been bothering you."**?

Answer (score 2):

After you have **finished bothering** someone you can say

> **Sorry to have bothered you**

since it proper and in the **past tense**. You can also still say

> **Sorry for bothering you**
>
> P1: Would you know what time it is?
>   P2: 10:15
>   P1: Thank you, sorry for bothering you.

which will sound more informal.

> **Sorry because I have been bothering you**

would not usually be used since it is **too wordy** and **Sorry...bother** already states the reason *(because)* you bothered them

> **Sorry for being a bother**

can be used in an **informal, self-deprecating** way